# How do I position an element up using HTML/CSS without leaving a void between the next section?

Tags: html, css

I am a novice trying to code my website, so if anyone with expertise with HTML/CSS can help, I would be greatly appreciative.  I have several sections laid out in rows.  In the problem at hand, I have a section that has three elements within it: a wavy image that spans the entire previous section, and then a container div that holds two other divs, laid out in a flex.  See image below:

[image]

I want to be able to raise the illustration of the mop up so that it intersects with the wavy blue image, while the bottom of the mop should be flush with the bottom section.  See my mockup in illustrator:

[image]

When I use position to adjust the mop up, I get a gap between the bottom of the divs and the next section.

[image]

The only idea I can come up with is to adjust each following section up by the amount I shifted the mop up, but that seems kind of messy and not as elegant as I would like it.  Anyone have any ideas as to what I should do so the css is less hackish?

Comment: Can you share you HTML and CSS code of this part of your website?

Comment: Its easier for everyone if you edit you post and use the snippet tool `<>` to post your html and css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use a negative margin like `margin-top: -50px` for the mop container/image with your current layout, or set the div with the blue wavy image to `position: absolute` and play around with the offsets. The latter makes sure that the element doesn't push siblings downwards.